# cannot extract images from bag file

Tags: ros, bagfile, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Ros Indigo. I am trying to extract images from a bag file, I am using this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 30 $(find image_view)/test.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/ci109/image_raw"/>
    <param name="filename_format" value="~/test/frame%06i.jpg"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

I am away of this question [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data) and this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9827/converting-a-bag-file-to-images/).
It seems like it is running fine but I do not see anything like

```
[ INFO] [1303939096.111425424]: Saved image frame0000.jpg
```

And I don't see any image in the `.ros` folder or the `~/test` folder that I created to test. Here is my output:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /extract/filename_format: /home/charis/test...
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.19

NODES
  /
    extract (image_view/extract_images)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [15728]
process[extract-2]: started with pid [15729]
[ INFO] [1464279324.985270766]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
[rosbag-1] process has finished cleanly
```

I did make sure that the bag file is in place. Basically, it seems that the console stays put for a while at

```
[ INFO] [1464288031.072128668]: Initialized sec per frame to 0.100000
```

then it says `process has finished cleanly` !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235291/cannot-extract-images-from-bag-file/) by [Samer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23151/samer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out that my images are compressed images and I just had to add this line to the launch file:

```
<param name="image_transport" value="compressed"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Samer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23151/samer/) with karma: 75 on 2016-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1